# Inserting text from text file into existing Excel worksheet with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to insert the contents of my text file into cell A1 on Sheet1 but all I get is the filename inserted instead of the contents of the text file.

```
$Path = 'C:\folder\Test.xlsx'
$Text='C:\folder\text.txt'
# Open the Excel document and pull in the 'Play' worksheet
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible=$true #For troubleshooting purposes only.

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Path) 
$page = 'Sheet1'
$ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}
# Set variables for the worksheet cells, and for navigation

$cells=$ws.Cells
$row=1
$col=1
$cells.item($Row,$col)=$Text
$col++
# Close the workbook and exit Excel
$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you set $Text to just the path to the file. You have to actually read the contents of the file with a cmdlet like Get-Content.

For example:

```
$Text = Get-Content 'C:\folder\text.txt'
```

However, depending on the contents of that text file, you may want to do that differently or you could end up with a messy result.